# Whats wrong with this CSS (attempt to create a "digg like" pagination footer)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a pagination footer for a page. Here is my Html snippet along with internal CSS:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <style="text/css">
ul{border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}

#pagination-digg li{
border:0; margin:0; padding:0;
font-size:11px;
list-style:none;
margin-right:2px;
}
#pagination-digg a{
border:solid 1px #9aafe5
margin-right:2px;
}
#pagination-digg .previous-off,
#pagination-digg .next-off {
border:solid 1px #DEDEDE
color:#888888
display:block;
float:left;
font-weight:bold;
margin-right:2px;
padding:3px 4px;
}
#pagination-digg .next a,
#pagination-digg .previous a {
font-weight:bold;
}
#pagination-digg .active{
background:#2e6ab1;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-weight:bold;
display:block;
float:left;
padding:4px 6px;
}
#pagination-digg a:link,
#pagination-digg a:visited {
color:#0e509e
display:block;
float:left;
padding:3px 6px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#pagination-digg a:hover{
border:solid 1px #0e509e
}
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<ul id="pagination-digg">
<li class="previous-off">«Previous</li>
<li class="active">1</li>
<li><a href="?page=2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=4">4</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=5">5</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=6">6</a></li>
<li><a href="?page=7">7</a></li>
<li class="next"><a href="?page=2">Next »</a></li>
</ul> 
    </body>
</html>
```

The code is actually from this tutorial [here](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/03/perfect-pagination-style-using-css.html), which is clearly wrong.

The footer does not render as it should, and the flickering on mousemove hover event seems to suggest that either padding, font-weight ormargins are being changed on the hover event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#pagination-digg a:hover{
border:solid 1px #0e509e;margin:-1px
}
```

Updated again. Some style codes aren't closed. Use the CSS code in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jWbzX/2/

Comment: Actually, there seems to be still something wrong with the CSS. Could you please take a look at the actual page I am using here: http://jsfiddle.net/fpPRL/  You will see that the previous 'button' is not being formatted correctly.

Comment: Because previous button is active on your example and It's container's class should be just previous, not previous-off.

Comment: Just like the next button. When next is inactive it's class should be next-off. Look at your css codes. You'll understand how it works.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Apologies, the fault was at my side. Thanks for pointing that out.